# Responsive Navigator in React Navigation

Tags: expo, react-navigation, responsive, react-navigation-v5

I've been using expo & react-navigation for developing on both mobile & desktop and so far it's awesome! However, I need to display bottom tab in mobile & drawer in desktop. I've been facing some trouble with applying different navigator in smaller & larger screens. We want to display tab in mobile & a sidebar in larger screens. The route structure is different between mobile & larger screen.
For example:
In mobile screens:

- Main Navigator

  - Tab Navigator

    - Screen A
    - Screen B
    - Screen C
  - Profile Stack Navigator
  - Settings Stack Navigator
    In mobile we just want the 3 screens to be inside the tab, while the other should not display the tab.
    In larger screens:
- Main Navigator

  - Drawer Navigator

    - Stack A

      - Screen A
      - Profile Stack Navigator (put the stack here, because we don't want the profile stack navigator to be displayed in drawer item list)
    - Stack B

      - Screen B
      - Settings Stack Navigator
    - Stack C

      - Screen C
        Notice that in larger screens, we want every screen to be inside the drawer navigator (as the sidebar would be persistent)

The first thing we can would be to do a conditional rendering (based on the dimensions), but several problems arises:

1. How would we type this in the screens?
2. The structure is different, how would we navigate? (the path would be also be different right?)

I'm thinking to create some kind of navigation wrapper that will receive navigation & current screen as the params. But not sure about this. If you guys have any thoughts or ever experienced this, please do share! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, if you resize a browser from/to desktop, then the navigation would reset because screens are not really the same (different instance).

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very [similar question](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/discussions/11661#discussion-5775664) on their github and the answer is to create a [custom navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/).

For now there is no way of achieving this, the main contributor said this:

> The stack navigators are not built to handle different layouts.